# C++ release allocated char* into string

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, char, strdup

I have tried to find an answer but couldn't see anything straight forward.

How do I free the allocated memory in the next snippet code:

`const char* attStr = strdup(OtherCharStr);
string str(attStr, strlen(attStr));
delete str; //???`

Comment: Use `free(attStr);` in this case.

Comment: Don't use `strdup`. Just do `std::string str(OtherCharStr);`. `std::string` already copies it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, but for some reason when i print the output i get garbage, i though that it is because the allocated memory by `str::string str(OtherCharStr)` is freed once i leave the function.

Comment: _"freed once i leave the function"_ - Your question doesn't include any information about it's use or an example of it returning the value from a function. Overall a **very** poor question. Return the `std::string` by value and let the compiler handle the optimization (RVO/NRVO).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, my question is good, your answers are garbage! "Don't use strdup. Just do std::string str(OtherCharStr);." i didn't ask you for alternative way to copy the string, I specifically asked how to free the allocated memory! If you don't have good or relevant answers then just go away.

Comment: Your comments make me sad. Good luck in achieving your future failures though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release attStr not the c++ string that will release its resources alone.

```
void func()
{
    const char* attStr = strdup(OtherCharStr);
    string str(attStr, strlen(attStr));
    free(attStr);
}//here str will release its own resources
```

Also you can do 
    string str = OtherCharStr;
an that's it. Only check what happens with OtherCharStr

Answer (score 3):

C++ uses idiom called [RIAA - Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). It means that object lifetime is driven by variable scope.

```
{
    std::string s("foo"); // variable s declaration and string initialization
    do_some_stuff(s);
    // end of scope of variable s - it is destroyed here
    // no need to free(s) or whatever
}
// variable s and the string doesn't exist here, no memory for it is allocated
```

This applies only for C++ objects that maintain its resources properly (are freeing them in the destructor). Simple pointers doesn't do it - you have to free them yourself:

```
const char *attStr = strdup(...);
// do something with attStr
free(attStr); // because strdup() documentation says you should free it with free()
```

Also notice that C++ uses `new` and `delete` rather than `malloc()` and `free()`:

```
std::string *strPointer = new std::string(...);
// RIAA doesn't work here, because strPointer is just plain pointer,
// so this is the case when you need to use free() or delete
delete strPointer;
```

I recommend to read something about [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) which are deleting the object they point to automatically. I'm getting pretty far from the original question but this topic is important to understand how C++ works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i enjoyed reading your answer and i really feel i understand it better now.